# JQM Click Event Delegation: Multiple result for Datepicker with JQM Datebox & SimpleDialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker, event-handling

I was looking for a way to select multiple dates using [JQMDateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/), and  my current solution works but I have an issue with event delegation that I can't seem to fix.

The application
I've an input box `id=date`with the Datebox implemented on. And I am using the datebox `method==set` to capture the selected date from user. Then I used the [JTSage SimpleDialog](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/) plugin for popup chaining, to collect time and hours for date.

The worklflow.
When a user clicks on the date field a datebox pops up asking the user to select date and once a date is selected another popup boxes comes up that ask for time and hours (Time & Hours) are associated to each date. When user clicks on Okay the select date, time and hours are put in a div below showing the selection. The user can then select more dates(time & hours) if needed that also will get added to the div for display and confirmation purpose.

The Problem
Every-time the user selects a new date, then time and hours. The same date/time/hours gets inserted into my div multiple times. Here's an example, only need one of each.

**Result**

```
Date: Dec 31 2014 22:00:00    First Selection
Date: Dec 30 2014 22:10:00    Second Selection
Date: Dec 30 2014 22:10:00    Second Selection
Date: Dec 29 2014 22:20:00    Third Selection
Date: Dec 29 2014 22:20:00    Third Selection
Date: Dec 29 2014 22:20:00    Third Selection
```

Here's my code.

**HTML**

```
<label  for="caredate">What date do you need care?</label>
<input  data-role="datebox" type="text" id="date" name="caredate" data-options='{"mode":"calbox", "useFocus":true }'>


<div id="inlinecontent" style="display: none;"  data-options='{"mode":"blank","blankContent":true,"blankContentAdopt":true,"headerText":"Time & Hours","headerClose":false}'>   
                <br />
                <label  for="caretime">What time shoud care start?</label>
                <input  data-role="datebox"   type="text"   id="time" name="caretime"   data-options='{"mode":"timeflipbox", "useFocus":true }'>
                <br />
                <label for="hours">Hours Needed?</label>
                <input type="range" name="hours" id="slider-10" data-highlight="true" min="1" max="12" step="1" value="0">
                <br />
                <a rel='close' data-role='button' id="datehrsvalue" href='#'> Save </a>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#reqservice",function () {
$('#date').bind('datebox', function(e, p) {
   if ( p.method === 'set' ) 
       {  
           e.stopImmediatePropagation()
           $('#inlinecontent').simpledialog2();
           $('#datehrsvalue').on("click", function()
                {
                    var ddate = $('#date').datebox('getTheDate');
            //.toString gives Date format, .split dvides the date on each space and return as an array .splice takes the second, third and forth values from the array & .join puts them with spaces and returns them in a format as MM, DD, YYYY
                    var cdate = ddate.toString().split(' ').splice(1,3).join(' ');
                    var dtime = $('#time').datebox('getTheDate');
                    var ctime = dtime.toString().split(' ').splice(4,1).join(' ');
                    $('#confdate').append('Date: ' + cdate + ' ');
                    $('#confdate').append(ctime + '<br/>');
                    $('#date').val('');
                }); 



         }
                 });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each time you launch the date time picker, you are creating a new click event for "#datehrsvalue", so the code runs multiple times. So instead of

```
$('#datehrsvalue').on("click", function()...
```

Within the p.method === 'set', instead use ***[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)*** to create the handler once on page create:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#reqservice', function () {
    $(document).on("click", '#datehrsvalue', function(){ ... });
});
```

The event delegation ensures that the click will be handled even if the DOM element does not exist at pagecreate.

Comment: I put your recommendation right below this line `$('#inlinecontent').simpledialog2();` but nothing shows up on the div anymore.

Comment: Here's what I did. `$('#date').on('datebox', function(e, p) {
    if ( p.method === 'set' ) 
     {          
         e.stopImmediatePropagation()
            $('#inlinecontent').simpledialog2();  
 $(document).on('pagecreate', "#reqservice",function () { 
 $(document).on("click", "#datehrsvalue", function(){`

Comment: @keez, I meant put the whole pagecreate and click outside of the datebox event. You pre-create the event once using event delegation, and then inside the datebox handler you only need to call $('#inlinecontent').simpledialog2();. Using off() is another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this from the lead ezanker provided it was a jquery mobile click event issue. The click event was firing multiple times. Here's a great [article](http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-jquery-multiple-event-triggering/) that talks about jquery event triggering. I solved it by unbinding the event before it's binded.

Removed this line

```
  $('#datehrsvalue').on("click", function()
```

Replaced with

```
   $(document).off('click', '#datehrsvalue').on('click', '#datehrsvalue',function(e) {
```